# How can a sh script determine if it was started as a cron job as opposed to interactive or background?

Tags: unix, cron, sh

I'd like to use the same scripting for cron and interactive, just wondering if there was a universal way over UNIX/Linux systems to easily make this determination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to return the name of the parent process with something like this: -

```
ps -ocommand= -p $PPID | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | awk '{print $1}'
```

For me this returned *konsole* when I ran this interactively.

or you could script in some logic to handle situations.

```
while getopts cm opt
do
case $opt in
        c)
                ##  Do crontask 
        ;;
        m)
                ##  Do manual
        ;;
        esac
done
```

Now when executing the script you can pass an option as an attribute like so :-

```
/use/local/bin/example.sh -m
/use/local/bin/example.sh -c
```

Comment: This one looks like the most universal.

Comment: I know that I did not ask this, but cron (in RHEL) also runs at jobs.  So there it doesn't look like there is a way to distinguish at jobs from cron jobs in cases.

Answer (score 2):

there is no universal way at all. using interactive/noninteractive shell detection or tty detection is not reliable either, as other cases than cron can have these characteristics. just add a variable in your cron entry. say you need to run test.sh, then use this instead.

```
$ RUNENV=cron ./test.sh
cron
cat ./test.sh 
#!/bin/sh
echo $RUNENV
```

This is fairly easy and reliable, if you control the cron setup.

Comment: I like this but it will not work on all UNIX/Linux systems.  SunOS for one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how portable this is, but on Linux you can run `tty` and check whether the output is a tty.

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/2
$ crontab -e
* * * * * echo $(tty) >> /home/paulo/cron_tty
[Wait a minute...]
$ cat /home/paulo/cron_tty
not a tty
```

Note that the tty will also not be set if the script is running non-interactively from something other than cron, but since you said you want to distinguish cron from interactive, that shouldn't be an issue.

Other than that, possibly the most robust solution is to add a switch to your script, telling it whether it is running from cron or not, as suggested in a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903559/detect-if-java-is-run-from-cron-or-through-shell).